# Find the largest number of pairs of adjacent cells such that the number in one cell of the pair divides into the other number in the pair.

Tags: optimization, contest-math, problem-solving

The numbers from 1 to 9 are written in a 3 × 3 grid of cells. Every cell has one number and no number is written more than once. Find the largest number of pairs of adjacent (sharing a side) cells such that the number in one cell of the pair divides into the other number in the pair.

I think 1 is meant to be in the centre because it divides every number but im not sure

Suggestions and solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible way to solve the question**

The max amount of possible adjacent cells is $12$, because a $3$x$3$ square has 12 possible side where cells could be adjacent.

Both $5,7$ could only be adjacent to $1$. The number $9$ could only be adjacent to $3$ or $1$.

Now you could construct an inelegent proof by contradiction, that a grid with $10$ or more adjacent side does not exist. And show this next example with $9$ adjacent sides:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{}
  5&8&4\\
  7&1&2\\
  9&3&6
\end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: Awsome solution man!